How do I extract texture data using Vulkan API at the extension/driver level?
I need to extract all textures from an application at the driver level, similar to GFXR and RenderDocs, but I am unclear on the main methodology. In Vulkan, texture data is transferred to GPU memory by the application rather than the driver. Based on my understanding and testing, the typical process appears to be:

Create a staging buffer.

The application copies pixel data to the staging buffer:


    void* hostData;
    vkMapMemory(device, stagingBufferMemory, 0, imageSize, 0, &data);  // Map GPU memory to host and copy data
    memcpy(data, srcPixels, static_cast<size_t>(imageSize));
    vkUnmapMemory(device, stagingBufferMemory);


Create a VkImage (another VkDeviceMemory).

Transition the VkImage layout to a GPU optimal layout.

Copy the staging buffer (linear data) to the VkImage using:


vkCmdCopyBufferToImage(commandBuffer, stagingBuffer, VkImage, etc...)

Transition the VkImage layout to a GPU optimal layout.

One approach to obtaining the texture data is to dump it before calling vkUnmapMemory. However, there is no guarantee the application will call vkUnmapMemory as it may keep it mapped indefinitely. Another potential method is to intercept vkCmdCopyBufferToImage, but if the application does not use a staging buffer and has pixels in a GPU-friendly format, this approach would also fail, resulting in swizzled pixel data that is difficult to recompose.
Could anyone familiar with GFXR or RenderDoc explain their general methodology for this process?
Thank you for your time.
Best regards,

"there is no guarantee the application will call vkUnmapMemory as it may keep it mapped indefinitely" Applications should keep such memory mapped indefinitely.

@NicolBolas I don't understand your comment. Most applications will call vkUnmapMemory right after the buffer is copied. Why are you saying otherwise?

Because they shouldn't. Mappable memory being mapped doesn't do anything. It doesn't stop the GPU from accessing it (Vulkan isn't OpenGL, and even GL can access mapped memory now). It doesn't cause performance problems. The only thing it does is take up space in your 64-bit address space, which you're never going to miss in real applications. As such, there is no reason to unmap mappable memory. Just keep it mapped all the time. That's what most applications do.

Also, I highly doubt that Vulkan programs that aren't tutorials, demos, or other trivial things will be unmapping memory after every modification.

On the "GPU-friendly format" being a direct upload to a swizzled layout part of this, that isn't possible. The CPU cannot directly map TILED_OPTIMAL layouts, as the layout is implementation-defined. That's a use case that must always use staging to make CPU-accessible.

Other things to think about:

Do you care about rendered textures? (May not be a CPU-side API to hook at all, other than the command buffer)
Do you care about correctly handling aliased formats? (Compute shader writes INT32 data, which magically turns into e.g. BC7 compressed images when accessed via a different ImageView).


@solidpixel I'd like to know just the main idea behind RenderDoc or GFXR since they are doing it. Yet, dig through thousands of lines of code and probably a decade of development isn't something to understand the algorithm isn't something simple either.

All of RenderDoc's interaction with Vulkan-accessing programs is done through Vulkan layers. A layer is a piece of code that can sit between the implementation and the application. Layers are often used during debugging, but implicit layers can register themselves in a way that they're always hooked in.
Exactly how this works is OS-specific, but the hooks are always there.
Once you have a layer, you can listen in on all interactions between the host and the Vulkan implementation. This gives you all the information you need to be able to extract whatever information you like.
But that doesn't mean that it's easy.
As you have seen, applications don't have to unmap memory immediately after copying to it. Indeed, this would cause poor performance, since mapping is not a trivial operation and keeping memory mapped has almost no downsides. So most real applications that allocate mappable memory will leave it mapped. And if that memory is allocated as coherent, they don't even have to call a function to make values they've written visible to Vulkan.
But that doesn't mean that there's no way to know when changes have happened.
Because Vulkan operations execute asynchronously relative to host operations, if the host writes data to a piece of memory, there must be some synchronization between the writes to that memory and any reads from it. vkQueueSubmit can handle this implicitly, so long as the host writes are themselves synchronized with the host call to vkQueueSubmit. But they don't have to be; the batch of work could have a wait on an event that gets set by the host. That event would have a memory barrier to make the bytes written by the host available to the GPU.
The point being that, while it is doable, it is also a very complicated process. RenderDoc is open-source, so one way to learn all of the details is to look at its implementation.
